# How to avoid getting 403 error from Github API?

Tags: php, github-api, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get every modified lines a user did on his Github account. I did a little PHP script, with some foreach() loops. The problem is that I get everytime a 403 error from the Github API.

I already tryied to change the header. I was doing this :

```
$get_options = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Dev-Purpose'));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$jsonurl = "https://api.github.com/users/" . $github_user . "/repos";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
```

So I changed to this :

```php
$get_options  = [
    'http' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => [
                    'User-Agent: e'
            ]
    ]
];
$context  = stream_context_create($get_options);

$jsonurl = "https://api.github.com/users/" . $github_user . "/repos";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
```

But it didn't solve the problem. I still get this 403 error.

I'm doing this to get every modified lines from a Github account :

```php
foreach ($repositeries as $id => $value) {
    $repo_name = $value["name"];
    $jsonurl = "https://api.github.com/repos/" . $github_user . "/" . $repo_name . "/commits";    
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
    $commits = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ($commits as $id => $value) {
        $sha = $value["sha"];
        $jsonurl = "https://api.github.com/repos/" . $github_user . "/" . $repo_name . "/commits/" . $sha;
        $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
        $datas = json_decode($json, true);
        /* Adding lines to vars */
        $totalLines = $totalLines + $datas["stats"]["total"];
        $addedLines = $addedLines + $datas["stats"]["additions"];
        $deletedLines = $deletedLines + $datas["stats"]["deletions"];
    }
}
```

The expected results are every statistics from Github Commits API.
The first time I launched the script, the very first loops worked, and I get something like 195 for `$totalLines`. But after looking into my PHP local server, I saw 403 errors for the other loops.

Anyone knows how I can fix this, so I can get every modified lines from a certain Github account ?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I would like to add that this script is very long to execute...

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are sending a Authorization header with each request. A HTTP 403 Forbidden response suggests that you are trying to access a private repository.